# Unpivot/unmelt to create dynamic columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like below:
I want to unmelt this dataframe such that the distinct IV values for the same I_S values go into separate columns, and same goes for the IC column.

```
df_1.columns
Index(['I_Y', 'I_DY', 'I_H', 'I_M', 'I_S', 'IB', 'ISZ'], dtype='object', name='BSF')

'I_Y', 'I_DY', 'I_H', 'I_M', 'I_S', 'IV',  'IC'
 2015   55      21      57     8     5.67  200
 2015   55      21      57     8     5.66  100
 2015   55      21      57     9     5.65  200
 2015   55      21      57     9     5.64  200
 2015   55      21      57     10    5.67  200
 2015   55      21      57     10    5.66  200
 2015   55      21      57     10    5.65  600
 2015   55      21      57     10    5.64  200
```

Desired output:

```
'I_Y', 'I_DY', 'I_H', 'I_M', 'I_S', 'IV1','IC1','IV2','IC2','IV3','IC3','IV4','IC4'
 2015   55      21      57     8    5.67   200   5.66  100
 2015   55      21      57     9    5.65   200   5.63  200
 2015   55      21      57     10   5.67   200   5.66  200  5.65  600  5.64  200
```

Since i do not know how many levels the IV can go, i was thinking of making it dynamic, and a column gets created for each level. (by level i mean the different IV values)

Comment: Unmelting your DF is probably a preprocessing step you want to do before you actually change some data. What are you trying to solve in the end?

Comment: For now..the desired output is my end :)

Comment: But why? Why not look at the original data if everything you want to do is look at it?

Comment: I guess data wrangling or data munging is always this unfair.. we always have the data in front..but we want to look at it differently..;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape, but first get all columns without `IV` and `IC` by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) and create counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), last sorting by second level of `MultiIndex` in columns and flatten `MultiIndex` by `f-string`s in list comprehension:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip("'")

cols = df.columns.difference(['IV','IC']).tolist()
g = df.groupby(cols).cumcount().add(1)
df1 = df.set_index(cols + [g]).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df1.columns = [f'{x}{y}' for x, y in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   I_DY  I_H  I_M  I_S   I_Y    IC1   IV1    IC2   IV2    IC3   IV3    IC4  \
0    55   21   57    8  2015  200.0  5.67  100.0  5.66    NaN   NaN    NaN   
1    55   21   57    9  2015  200.0  5.65  200.0  5.64    NaN   NaN    NaN   
2    55   21   57   10  2015  200.0  5.67  200.0  5.66  600.0  5.65  200.0   

    IV4  
0   NaN  
1   NaN  
2  5.64
```

Comment: Super stuff!! Genuis

Comment: Like Nadal on clay.